# an error webdriver (get) when using selenium in google colab

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

I tried to search the answers by Google, but they didn't work. I feel quite upset now.
[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

You're using Chrome driver from `webdriver`. Thus, you have to install Chrome in your environement. Since Google colab runs the python kernel in the isolated which does not have any Chrome or GUI packages.

You need to run in the different environment with pre-installed chrome instead of Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

I make a library to make it easier

```py
!pip install kora -q
from kora.selenium import wd as browser

browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: I got the same error 

WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1